# align histogram bins by 5

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: Current Histogram View]

Hello, I have some data that are arranged in bins of size 5.  However, the axis do not line up with the bins and are therefore difficult to see where they start and end.

I either want to redefine the axis so that the labels are in increments of 5 aligning with the minimum value (axis would have labels 204, 209, 214 etc.)

or for the bins to start on an interval of 5 dependent upon the minimum value in the series.  For example, you can see that the minimum value in the data set I have provided is 204.  As of now the bins visually appear to be 204-208, 209-213, etc. Once a change is made the bins would then be 200-204, 205-209, etc.

```
data <- data.frame(c(218, 213, 234, 223, 262, 251, 240, 235, 236, 237, 245, 229, 261, 269, 256, 239, 255, 258, 221, 231, 246, 248, 206, 204, 211))

ggplot(data=data, aes(data)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(min(data), max(data), by =5),
             col="black",
             fill="grey") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n=20)) +
  labs(x="Data Value", y="Count", title = "Histogram of Data Values") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=20))
```

Comment: Well, which option are you asking about here specifically?

Comment: I would prefer the first option, but whichever option is simpler to implement is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second option is the simpler one to implement:

```
data <- data.frame(x = c(218, 213, 234, 223, 262, 251, 240, 235, 236, 237, 245, 229, 261, 269, 256, 239, 255, 258, 221, 231, 246, 248, 206, 204, 211))

ggplot(data, aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 5, boundary = 5, fill = "white", colour = "black") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1000, by = 5))
```

[image]

`bindwidth =` sets the bins to be multiples of 5. `boundary =` sets the edge of one of the bins (even if it's outside the range, they'll all end on `boundary` + **n** * `binwidth`, for any arbitrary **n**).

The first one is somewhat more involved, since you have to specify the minimum and maximum of your data in both the `geom` and the `scale`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 5, boundary = min(data$x), fill = "white", colour = "black") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(data$x), max(data$x) + 4, by = 5))
```

[image]

Comment: Both solutions are perfect.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For the first option, I think you can enforce the breaks in `scale_x_continuous` using `breaks` instead of `pretty_breaks`:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(data)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(min(data), max(data), by =5),
                 col="black",
                 fill="grey") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(data), max(data), by = 5)) +
  labs(x="Data Value", y="Count", title = "Histogram of Data Values") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=20))
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is successful and does exactly what I asked for, however, if the data value 240 is changed to 272, giving a new maximum, that data value does not adjust and the count of the data values totals 24 rather than 25.

Comment: Fair enough. Plus, @Brian has shown both solutions- I agree that his is the correct answer.